# SwiftUI struct intialised using specified variable from another struct

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an array, buildingData, that contains Building structs with numeric properties (currently stored as strings). I am making a view that provides details of a single building and which shows a ranking number for each of its properties relative to the other buildings in buildingData.

Rather than explicitly writing each row of list, I would prefer a generic view struct, rankingRow, something like this:

```
    struct rankingRow : View {
        var building : Building
        var dataDescription : String
        var dataValue: String
        
        var body: some View {
            HStack {
                Text(dataDescription)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                Text(dataValue)
                Spacer()
                RankingNumber(      //  Takes a rank (Int) and a size (Double) and makes a ranking graphic
                    rank: buildingData.sorted(by: { Double($0.overallSqm) ?? 0 > Double($1.overallSqm) ?? 0 }).firstIndex(of: building)! + 1,
                    size:28
                    )
            }
        }
    }
```

However, I’m not clear how to concisely pass this struct the name of the property to be ranked (e.g. overallSqm in the above example). How do I change the struct to generate the list using something like:

```
           List {
                             rankingRow(building:building, dataDescription:"Total Space (m2):", dataValue: building.overallSqm, rankedBy: .overallSqm)
                             rankingRow(building:building, dataDescription:”Public Space (m2):", dataValue: building.publicSqm, rankedBy: .publicSqm)
            }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now your RankingRow(s) depend(s) on buildingData. If you add the rank (and other
data the graph might need) as a parameter you can simplify the view. Calculation of the
rank is preferably done in (an extension of) the model (or ViewModel).

To iterate over the properties of a building you can implement subscript on Building.
Using an enum prevents the need to check for invalid keys. You can add an extension to
the key to conveniently provide your dataDescription. Use ForEach to iterate over the
building properties in SwiftUI.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Building {
    let overallSqm: String
    let publicSqm : String
}

// identifying buildings is necessary for calculating the rank, one of the options
// is to make Buidling conform to equatable
extension Building: Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs: Building, rhs: Building) -> Bool {
        return lhs.overallSqm == rhs.overallSqm && lhs.publicSqm == rhs.publicSqm
    }
}

extension Building {

    enum PropertyKey {
        case overallSqm
        case publicSqm
    }

    subscript(key: PropertyKey) -> String {
        switch key {
            case .overallSqm: return self.overallSqm
            case .publicSqm: return self.publicSqm
        }
    }
}

extension Building {
    func rank(in buildings: [Building], key: Building.PropertyKey) -> Int {
        (buildings.sorted { (Double($0[key]) ?? 0) < (Double($1[key]) ?? 0) }.firstIndex { self == $0 } ?? 0) + 1
    }
}

extension Building.PropertyKey {
    var dataDescription: String {
        switch self {
        case .overallSqm: return "Total Space (m2):"
        case .publicSqm: return "Public Space (m2):"
        }
    }
}

struct rankingRow: View {

    let building       : Building
    let dataDescription: String
    let dataValue      : String
    let rank           : Int
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(dataDescription)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
            Text(dataValue)
            Spacer()
            RankingNumber(rank: rank, size: 28)
        }
    }
}

struct RankingNumber: View {
    let rank: Int
    let size: CGFloat
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Rank: \(rank)")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    let buildings: [Building] = [
        Building(overallSqm: "1000.0", publicSqm: "700.0" ),
        Building(overallSqm: "1500.0", publicSqm: "600.0" ),
        Building(overallSqm: "2000.0", publicSqm: "1200.0")
    ]
    
    @State var building: Building = Building(overallSqm: "1000.0", publicSqm: "700.0")

    let keys: [Building.PropertyKey] = [.overallSqm, .publicSqm]
            
    func rank(for building: Building, key: Building.PropertyKey) -> Int {
        (buildings.sorted { (Double($0[key]) ?? 0) < (Double($1[key]) ?? 0) }.firstIndex { building == $0 } ?? 0) + 1
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(keys, id: \.self) { key in
                rankingRow(
                    building       : self.building,
                    dataDescription: key.dataDescription,
                    dataValue      : self.building[key],
                    rank           : self.rank(for: self.building, key: key))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time - works well! Useful tips and an approach I wouldn't have considered.